# Combine Similar Classes with jQuery .first()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove a common class between multiple divs but only target the first `p` in each div to remove that class name.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thing thing--one">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p class="extended-content">A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing--two">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p class="extended-content">A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing--three">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p class="extended-content">A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I do this:

```
$(".thing--one p, .thing--two p, .thing--three p").first().removeClass("extended-content");
```

It only removes the first `extended-content` class from the first `p` in the `thing--one` class.

So, currently I have it written out like this:

```
$(".thing--one p").first().removeClass("extended-content");
$(".thing--two p").first().removeClass("extended-content");
$(".thing--three p").first().removeClass("extended-content");
```

Which works, but that feels and seems really bloated and not the best way to go about removing a common class in those three divs.

Any ideas on how to make that a bit more semantic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps

```js
$(".thing").each(function(i) {
  $(this).find("p").first().removeClass("extended-content");
});
```

```css
.extended-content {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thing thing--one">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p class="extended-content">A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing--two">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p class="extended-content">A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing--three">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p class="extended-content">A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use index selector **[`:eq(x)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** that selects the element at index `x` within the matched set, like :

```
$(".thing--one p:eq(0), .thing--two p:eq(0), .thing--three p:eq(0)").removeClass("extended-content");
```

If you want to loop through them it will be better to use jQuery method **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** :

```
$(".thing").map(function() {
    $('p:eq(0)', this).removeClass("extended-content");
});
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".thing--one p:eq(0), .thing--two p:eq(0), .thing--three p:eq(0)").removeClass("extended-content");
}, 500);
```

```css
.extended-content {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thing thing--one">
      <h2>This title 1</h2>
      <p class="extended-content">A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing--two">
      <h2>This title 2</h2>
      <p class="extended-content">A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing--three">
      <h2>This title 3</h2>
      <p class="extended-content">A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is functionally exactly the same as what you have that does work, but I consider it a bit friendlier on the eye...

```
$(".thing--one, .thing--two, .thing--three").each(function() {
    $(this).find("p").first().removeClass("extended-content");
});
```

It finds all the container elements and then runs a `.find()` on the contents, finding the first `<p>` tag.

Unless there's a reason not to, you could always change it to...

```
$(".thing").each(function() { etc..
```